# Can max be coerced to return only a float

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class that has two attributes (index and value).  I want to be able to call max and return only the value(which is a float).

```
p = [Point(1, 23.33), Point(2, 12.3)]
max(p)
#<Point object at 0x1052d4eb8> 
# I would like to see 23.33
# float(max(p)) returns the float but I want to be able to use the max function by it self
```

Is there a method in the data model that I can override to force `max` to return just the float?  The entire class below.

Python 3.6

```
class Point:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
      """ a set of data indexed by time """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      def __init__(self, index, value):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
          self._index = index                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
          self._value = value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

      def __float__(self):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
          return float(self._value)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

      def __add__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          return float(self._value) + other                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

      def __radd__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
          return self.__add__(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

      def __lt__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          return self._value < float(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

      def ___le__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
          return self._value <= float(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

      def __eq__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          return self._value == float(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

      def __ne__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          return self._value != float(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

      def __gt__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          return self._value > float(other)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

      def __ge__(self, other):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
          return self._value >= float(other)
```

Comment: This sounds like a really bad idea. Just call `float`.

Comment: do you have have a method to override? why not just define a function that does the coercion as a member function so you can then do: `p.max()` ?

Comment: Also, `___le__` has an extra `_`, and you should check the type of the other operand in your operator overloads (and return `NotImplemented` for unsupported other operands).

Comment: I'm curious. Why you do need this weird behavior?

Comment: `max` is going to give the maximum of the objects you feed to it, it isn't going to do an automatic conversion - that's not its job.

Comment: sounds like `float(max(p))` is the best solution.  I wanted to avoid calling the `float` on a list of Points for purely aesthetic reasons.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max), you can use any iterable: for instance you can iterate the values like this:

```
points = [Point(1, 23.33), Point(2, 12.3)]
m = max(p._value for p in points)
```

Or iterate using `float`:

```
m = max(float(p) for p in points)
```